# My activity behaves as singleTask on one device and normally on the other. Why?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have built an APK with an activity that behaves differently on different devices and I can't figure out why.  The activity does not define a [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and the launching activities are third party file browsers, email clients, google drive, etc.

On my Samsung Galaxy S5 phone device (Android 4.4.2):

When I launch my activity, it is pushed on to the current task's stack.  In other words, it has the default, expected behavior.

On my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (Android 4.3) phablet device:

When I launch my activity, it is always pushed on to a task stack containing only instances of my activity (if one exists, it starts a new task stack if one doesn't).
Hitting the back button from within my activity pops the activity off the stack and I return to other instances of my activity rather than to the activity that launched me.

What I want:

I do not want single task or single instance behavior, just the default Android behavior.  Other activities/viewers installed on the device do not seem to exhibit this behavior.

```
observed launch behavior by android version.
-------------------------------------------------------
|Android Version                  |Behavior           |
-------------------------------------------------------
|4.4.2                            |Default            |
|4.3                              |SingleTask         |
|4.2.2                            |Default            |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got to the bottom of the issue.  It appears that Note 3 and the Galaxy S5 had different file explorers or different versions of the file explorer installed on each.  When I installed the exact same explorer APK on both the note and the S5, they ended up behaving the same.

It appears that it was the launcher that decided to modify the ACTION_VIEW intent with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag or something similar.